# Windows phone 8.1 Development. Get Device Information

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, device

I want to get my devices information

- Manufacturer
- Name
- OS information

Info along those lines

How do I do this?

I've been trying to use Microsoft.Phone.dll found in:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\

but that gives the error `cannot find type system.systemexception in module mscorlib.dll`.

Comment: Did you check [DeviceStatus class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus(v=vs.105).aspx) and [DeviceExtendedProperties Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties(v=vs.105).aspx)?

Comment: Using visual studio 2012 and working on Windows Phone 8.0 there isn't a problem with the above but when I tried it using Visual studio 2013 express with Windows Phone 8.1 that is what causes the issue.